# How to navigate to the next page of a site using css selectors

Tags: python, html, css, scrapy

I'm extracting property information from a website [(Find Properties For Sale)](https://www.propertypro.ng/property-for-sale). I've been able to scrape the first page. But when I tried to scrape data from the next page, my code duplicated the data from the first page. How do I correct this?
Here is my approach:

```
next_page = response.css("ul.pagination li.page-item a.page-link::attr(href)").get()
   if next_page is not None:
      next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
      yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

Comment: The first item that selector matches, is the `⋘` pagination link, which has its href set to the exact same `/property-for-sale` again, which you are already currently on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xpath expression:

```py
next_page = response.xpath("//a[@alt='view next property page']").css("::attr(href)").get()
```